# How to use CsvFile().load() in PyOpenMS for importing a MRM (Multiple Reaction Monitoring) transition list

Tags: python

I'm trying to import a CSV file which contains my transition list for MRM data.  I haven't been able to find any documentation on evaluating MRM data in PyOpenMS so I've taking some code from the PyOpenMS OpenSwath documentation.  Here is my code:

```
from pyopenms import *

chroms = MSExperiment()
library = TargetedExperiment()
MzMLFile().load("Sample1.mzML", chroms)
CsvFile().load("TransitionList.csv", library)
```

I receive a TypeError:
load() takes exactly 4 positional arguments (2 given)

The PyOpenMS documentation lists the 4 arguments for load: (self, filename, is_, ie_, first_n)

I have the filename correct.  But I'm not sure if I'm using "library" correctly.  I don't know what to use for "is_", "ie_", "first_n".

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Having a look in the [documentation](https://abibuilder.cs.uni-tuebingen.de/archive/openms/Documentation/nightly/html/classOpenMS_1_1CsvFile.html#ad84ff1aded90af020b5435338b7af073), the function CsvFile().load() takes four arguments:

1. String *filename*
2. char *is* (the character that seperates items, e.g. '\t' or ',' or ';' (tab, comma, semicolon, etc.))
3. bool *ie* (whether every item is enclosed)
4. Int *first_n* (Only the given number of lines are read, starting from the beginning of the file. -1 probably means the whole file is read)

The docu also states that at the moment CsvFile only supports loading, so there is no method to store the file content into the TargetedExperiment() object.

After having done some [research](https://openms.de/documentation/classOpenMS_1_1TargetedExperiment.html#details), I don't see a method to do what you intend.